# While opening Chrome browser from selenium error occuring

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Browser is opening but [Not secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7WCu.png) is showing in header and 'Disable Extension' is showing.  After that chrome.exe is stopped working.
Chrome verison is 57.0 and selenium jar file is 3.0.1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Software\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    //WebDriver wd= new FirefoxDriver();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Software\\chromedriver_win32_V2.9\\chromedriver.exe");

     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
     WebDriver wd= new ChromeDriver();


    wd.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are observing?

Comment: Can you update the question with the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to update your Chrome driver which you are using for automation. It can be 2.28 version and Try with these lines of code.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromepath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: i have checked it in chrome driver version 2.9 and 2.8 but the sissue is still esisting. Please find the attached link https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve4ub.png    If i try the same for firefox browser, then showing  "moveto did not match a known command".

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you created chrome options but you have not included that while instantiating your chrome driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Software\\chromedriver_win32_V2.9\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("test-type");
```

You forgot to include options to the chrome driver, below is the fix.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

OR

As per Chrome Driver documentation to set options as capability below is the code.

```
 DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
 options.addArguments("test-type");
 caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

Let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: driver = new ChromeDriver(options); helps to disable the extension. but still in google chrome is showing " Not secure data". Please find the link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve4ub.png

Comment: If i try the same for firefox browser, then showing  "moveto did not match a known command".

Comment: Updated my answer for chrome browser, verify it once

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium 3.x, Chrome driver 2.28 & above and Google Chrome 57.x use the ChromeOptions Class to to get rid of all dependencies as below:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: still same error is occuring.  Apart from chrome driver issue, how can i solve the Firefox driver issue?

Comment: error trace-
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"5572.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'

Comment: @AbhijitDatta The piece of code I provided is to handle the certificate issue which you were observing for which you provided an attachment. I am pretty sure you don't see those warnings anymore. How to solve the Firefox driver issue and the WebDriverException, we will address in another thread. So if this Answer caters to your Question can you accept the Answer as a solution to to your Question to close the discussion thread? Thanks.

Comment: Dev, thanks for your reply.. but i am facing the same issue..dnt knw hw to solve this..apart from above piece of code, do u hv another option?

Comment: @AbhijitDatta I use a lot of ChromeOptions and you may not need all of them. Update me with the error you are facing. I will solve it for you.

Comment: Please find the link for refereence https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7WCu.png while i am running my code

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 29875
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:01:03'

Comment: Can you remove the gecko related System.setProperty from your code & paste your current code in the Question area along with the latest stacktrace?